# How do you stop duplicate outputs from an array?

Tags: android, arrays, string, duplicates

I have an array of words. When the activity launches it displays a word, and then when you click the screen, it displays another random word from the array. I was able to get this far (with some help) but I'm a little stuck. When you click the screen to display a new word, how can I make sure the word hasn't been displayed from the array already. Here is what I have so far.

```
private String[] myString;
public static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.study);

    //Takes a random item from array and creates string
    Resources res = getResources();
    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.list);
    String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

    //Displays random array string in TextView
    TextView wordTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
    wordTextView.setText(q);

    //Set up click listener for new word
    View newWord = findViewById(R.id.word);
    newWord.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.word:
        //Takes a random item from array and creates string
        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

        //Displays random array string in TextView
        TextView wordTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        wordTextView.setText(q);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think about this, you have two ways to do it:

1. After displaying a word, remove it from your list.  Then, the next time you pick a random word from the list, it won't be there.  This only works if you have a list you can modify.
2. Keep track of the words you've shown already, and if you happen to select a word you've previously selected, just select another

Comment: Yeah, I guessed those were my options. I'm new to android programming so I'm not to sure implement either option. I can figure things out if I have a starting position. Any ideas?

Comment: well, this is just java, so you can use an `ArrayList`, either to hold your list of words and remove items, or to hold a list of words you've displayed.  Are you new to android programming, or programming in general?

Comment: New to android programming and sort of new to programming. I'm a web developer so I have some experience with javascript and xml, but even so, programming with no html or css along side is new to me.

Comment: I would advise against #2.  If you start out with a large list, say length 50, and get down to ~2 Strings left, you will find that getting random values will take a while.  That's a 96% chance of having to select a new String again, meaning you might expect to make 25 random selections before getting a working answer.

This is obviously an exceptional situation, however I would advise against it as a matter of good practice/habit.

Comment: @Matt - agreed.  I've seen a dailywtf article based on someone who did that.  Though "select another" could be done differently than just picking another random number.

Comment: @Nader That's certainly true.  But since he said he was new to (non-web) programming, I figured it'd be better to clarify for him.  And throwing in a small explanation never hurts :)

Comment: @Matt, oh, i'm not complaining :)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be using an [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  If you want to keep the content, then it might take 2 ArrayLists.

It's pretty straightforward actually:

```
List wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
List usedList = new ArrayList<String>();

String s = wordsList.get(rgenerator.nextInt(wordsList.size()));

wordsList.remove(s);
usedList.add(s);
```

The second list is optional based on if you want to have a list of the words you've used.  If you don't need it, then you can remove the "usedList" lines.  Sorry if there are any mistakes.  Wrote this a bit hastily.  In either case, look up ArrayList in Javadocs and you'll understand it a bit better.  You're actually removing the String from the ArrayList, so you will not have to worry about repeats in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Thats a lot of help/. Am I able to write the list out in an array.xml and call it into the list? If so, do I use an array, a string array, some other way?